# How to use the VXYModelMapper with QStandardItemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, charts, qml

I want to add lines and points to a QML ChartView based on a model in C++.

In QML i did the following:

```
ChartView {
    id: chart

    DateTimeAxis {
        id: axisX
        format: "HH:mm:ss"
        min: new Date()
    }

    ValueAxis {
        id: axisY
        min: 0
        max: 200
    }

    VXYModelMapper {
        id: modelMapper
        model: lineModel // QStandardModel in C++
        series: line
        firstRow: 1
        xColumn: 1 
        yColumn: 2
    }
}
```

In C++ i did the following:

```
lineModel = new QStandardItemModel;
static const QHash< int, QByteArray > lineRoles {
    { 0, "id" },
    { 100, "x" },
    { 101, "y" }
};
lineModel->setItemRoleNames( lineRoles );

QStandardItem *line = new QStandardItem("Temp");
lineModel->appendRow(line);
line->setData(100, 10);
line->setData(101, 50);
```

The point never shows up. Is it because the xColumn and the yColumn of the ChartView are not right? Or do i add the point to the model wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[VXYModelMapper](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtcharts-vxymodelmapper.html) requires that the model have several columns, for example in your case you set the property `xColumn: 1` indicating that it is the second column and `yColumn: 2` which is the third column, but your model only has one column(the index start at 0 in the models.).

An example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QDateTime>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel lineModel(100, 3);// 100 rows and 3 columns

    for (int row = 0; row < lineModel.rowCount(); row++) {
        QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem(QString::number(row));
        QDateTime time = QDateTime::currentDateTime().addSecs(row);
        QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem(QString::number(time.toMSecsSinceEpoch()));
        QStandardItem *item3 = new QStandardItem(QString::number(row*row));
        lineModel.setItem(row, 0, item1);
        lineModel.setItem(row, 1, item2);
        lineModel.setItem(row, 2, item3);
    }

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("lineModel", &lineModel);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtCharts 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ChartView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: chart

        DateTimeAxis {
            id: axisX
            format: "HH:mm:ss"
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisY
            min: 0
            max: 10000
        }

        LineSeries{
            id: line
            axisX: axisX
            axisY: axisY
        }

        VXYModelMapper {
            id: modelMapper
            model: lineModel // QStandardModel in C++
            series: line
            firstRow: 1
            xColumn: 1
            yColumn: 2
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

<sub>In the following link you can find the complete [example](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/48687705).</sub>

---

**PySide2:**

```
import os
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQml

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    lineModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(100, 3)

    for row in range(lineModel.rowCount()):
        item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        item1.setData(row, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        time = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(row)
        item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        item2.setData(time.toMSecsSinceEpoch(), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        item3 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        item3.setData(row**2, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        lineModel.setItem(row, 0, item1)
        lineModel.setItem(row, 1, item2)
        lineModel.setItem(row, 2, item3)

    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine() ;
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("lineModel", lineModel);
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml")))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sye.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Does that mean that i need a new model for each line?

Comment: each column can be a line, or you can create several models, what you want.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Is the conversion to string `new QStandardItem(QString::number(row*row));` necessary?

Comment: @tauran No, but if you realize it is irrelevant in the underlying problem :-)

Comment: It is inefficient. I tried the same with PySide2 and it doesn't work without conversion to string.

Comment: @tauran 
Inefficient? Could you explain why you point that out? On the other hand PySide2 / PyQt5 are a binding of Qt5 but that does not mean that the methods work the same, for example in C ++ the classes can have different constructors but in Python not, so there are limitations and advantages in each language, if you want to use floating instead of strings, use the constructor item = QStandardItem() then use the setData (number, Qt.DisplayRole) method

Comment: Well somewhere inside QML the string values have to be parsed back to floating point values. That's inefficient and therefore I point it out. I would be interested if it works in C++ with floats. That would mean it's a bug in PySide2.

Comment: @tauran It is not a bug directly since the docs: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QStandardItem.html#PySide2.QtGui.QStandardItem do not indicate that behavior, but a limitation that has, anyway I have added the appropriate method in PySide2. The above is for PySide2 but speaking of C ++ is not inefficient either since the conversion is not heavy and also there is always going to be data conversion in QML if you send data from c ++.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188267/discussion-between-tauran-and-eyllanesc).